# SQL query returns double data

Tags: c#, sql, duplicates

```
 var result = Context.ItemSet
    .OrderBy(o => o.Index)
    /*.Include(t => t.Group) with this, item with id 500 is outputted 4 times, without it is outputted 2 times*/
    .ToList();

 for (int i = 0; i < result.Count(); i++)
 {
      Debug.WriteLine("-"+i);
      Debug.WriteLine(result[i].Id);
 }
```

The above code outputs the following:

```
>      -0
>       1
>      -1
>      11
>      -2
>      12
>      -3
      ...
>     -30
>      17
>     -31
>     206
>     -32
>     500 //
>     -33
>     500 //duplicate
>     -34
>     203
```

Why does the resultlist contain the same data multiple times and how can I prevent that? I can*not* use `select distinct id` because I need **all** columns.

Comment: Is the `Id` field actually unique?  What happens if you run the query against the database directly (without involving C#)?

Comment: yes, it is unique because when running the query in the database it returns just one row with the id 500

Comment: if you go in the database and select * from itemset where id=500 how many records do you get?

Comment: just one @RuiLima

Comment: Do you have a `GROUP BY` clause?

Comment: @thestruggleisreal Can you try the following: `var result = Context.ItemSet.Single(t => t.Id == 500).ToList();`? Can you check if this throws an `InvalidOperationException`?

Comment: it throws an InvalidOperationException @vinicius.ras 
(btw toList() is not possible with Single)

Comment: no @Symon just the orderby in the question

Comment: Calling `Single()` throws `InvalidOperationException` when the query returns more than one object (docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.single?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Linq_Queryable_Single__1_System_Linq_IQueryable___0__)), which is a strong indicator that your data source contains multiple entries with `Id = 500`. If running the query in the database returns a single record with `id=500` as you said before, then I can only suggest you try to verify the SQL generated when calling `ToList()` and manually check if it is correct.

Comment: There seems to be something wrong with your mapping. Could you post you mapping? It seems it is doing some cross join of sorts. It might get exponential worse with time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A further look into the Group table was the clue:
Two Groups had stored the Item with id 500. Changing that fixed the duplicates issue. I still get an Invalid OP Exception on another point in the code because of a circular reference problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = Context.ItemSet
.OrderBy(o => o.Index)
.Include(t => t.Group) 
.Select(t => t.id)
.Distinct()
.ToList();
```

Don't do this, the real problem seems to be in the mappings, applying this you most likely hide something really bad, like an unwanted right join or cross join of sorts. A simple include should not bring duplicated records, so it must be something wrong with the mappings. Possible even trying to access to both `many` sides in the wrong way. 
Out of curiosity is this the database mapping the following?

```
 ItemSet <(n)--(m)> Group
```

Sorry, I know this is not yet an answer, but it's too much text to put in as a comment, plus can't really format the comment

Comment: I have Item 1-to-0...1 Group relation and yes, without include it also brings duplicates. With include, it just brings more duplicates

Comment: We need to see the actual model. Are you sure that the data returned is not what is in the databases? ItemSet seems to be a set of items, in such case I'd expect to see an IdItemSet shown for several IdItem, something like: (IdItemSet, IdItem) (1, 10) (1, 20) -- Set 1 with items 10 and 20.